# include compiled through command prompt static library in qt project

Tags: qt, static, hyperlink, makefile

I’m trying to make a simple static library, like:
my.h

```
void    My();
```

my.cpp

```
#include "my.h"
#include "stdio.h"

void My()
{
    printf("Hello, world");
}
```

If I made it in qtcreator, I can call My() function in other project like:

.pro

```
INCLUDEPATH +=  c:/Users/PC/my
LIBS    +=  -Lc:/Users/PC/my/debug -lmy
```

.cpp

```
#include <my.h>
....
My();
```

When compiling the library, the makefile is created by qmake. If I try to compile as stated in makefile through command prompt, I get some other object and library files. Then if I include them into my project, I obtain error:

> undefined reference to `My()'.

How to link static library through command prompt and then include it into project?